# Make Open CTI demo adapter work with 3rd party APIs

Tags: apex, integration, opencti

I am trying to make Open CTI demo adapter Dialer work with Call Rail APIs. **Call Rail does not provide any package to integrate with dialer**. So my only option is to go with Call Rail APIs. I found a single endpoint which Call Rail provides to make outbound call. I tried this endpoint in the postman and it does ring on specified numbers.

**I also made the same http request from makeCall() of demo adapter. API call was successful but in dialer I am not hearing any ring or not able to listen if any person talks on other end.**

What I have to do to make demo adapter work like an actual phone.

[Call Rail API Documentation](https://apidocs.callrail.com/#creating-an-outbound-phone-call)